# Cannot convert to `AnyObject?`?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

In the creation of a swift iOS app, I needed to handle the event of a UIButton press outside of the parent view controller, so I created a (very simple) protocol to delegate that responsibility to a different class:

```
import UIKit
protocol MyButtonProtocol {
    func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton)
}
```

However, when I try to addTarget to a UIButton with that protocol, I get this error: `Cannot convert value of type 'MyButtonProtocol' to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'`. Shouldn't *anything* be able to be converted to `AnyObject?`? Here is my main code:

```
import UIKit
class MyView: UIView {
    var delegate: MyButtonProtocol
    var button: UIButton
    init(delegate: MyButtonProtocol) {
        self.delegate = delegate
        button = UIButton()
        //... formatting ...
        super.init(frame: CGRect())
        button.addTarget(delegate, action: "buttonPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        addSubview(button)
        //... more formatting ...
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`AnyObject` is the protocol to which all *classes* conform.
To define a protocol which can only adopted by classes, add
`: class` to the definition:

```
protocol MyButtonProtocol : class {
    func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton)
}
```

Without that modification,

```
var delegate: MyButtonProtocol
```

can be a `struct` or `enum` type and that is not convertible to `AnyObject`.

Answer (score 0):

```
//i hope it will work
import UIKit
class MyView: UIView {
  var delegate: MyButtonProtocol
var button: UIButton
init(delegate: MyButtonProtocol) {
    self.delegate = delegate
    button = UIButton()
    //... formatting ...
    super.init(frame: CGRect())
    button.addTarget(delegate, action: Selector("buttonPressed:") forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    addSubview(button)
    //... more formatting ...
}
}
```